# I have to convert the react component to a4 size pdf even when it is open in the mobile how can i do that

Tags: reactjs, pdf

the problem using some common html to pdf library is that when i try to convert the html to pdf it just convert the pdf what is shown in the screen like in mobile the content is not shown fully so i want the full content to be converted to pdf, is it possible to do that in the client side.

secondly is that the component may have a scrollbar as i have to fit it in the a4 size but it it possible to show whole data with out scroll in the pdf.

I have looked for many library but have not found any.